# Accessing Port while starting Websphere Server

Tags: websphere

i am facing the issue in webshpere ..the server is not staringReading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3028I: Conflict detected on port 8896. Likely causes: a) An instance of
the server server1 is already running b) some other process is
using port 8896
ADMU3027E: An instance of the server may already be running: server1
ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error:
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMU3027E: An
instance of the server may already be running: server1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused when the services don't shut down correctly and the java.exe processes hold a lock on the applications port. (8896).

To resolve this problem you can use one of the following options.

1) Open your taskmanager and end task the java.exe process for your JVM that is holding a lock on the servers port then restart the JVM from the WebSphere console

2) You can restart the physical server so the java.exe process shuts down and releases the port. Once the server starts back up you can start JVM and bring the application up.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems quite explicit: another program is using port 8896. 
To verify this you can use these commands:

- (Linux) sudo netstat -lptu|grep 8896
- (Windows) netstat -a -b (or other tools)

You can decide to stop the process that create the conflict or change the ports used by WAS:

- [Updating ports in existing profile](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tins_updatePorts.html)